# 'Stop-Function' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file" : Powershell- DbaTools

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I installed Dbatools in offline mode, but I can't find few functions, e.g.

Write-function, stop-function, DbainstancePramter

> "The term 'Stop-Function' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file"

Comment: Did you try [`Import-Module` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Import-Module) to _explicitly_ add the `Dbatools` module to the current session?

Comment: Thank Josef for your reply.  Imported dba tools cmdlet  import-module -name cmdlet after that i didn't see any error. Can you suggest further.

Comment: Try `import-module Dbatools -PassThru` and `(Get-module Dbatools).ExportedCommands` to ensure that import was successful

Comment: Hi Josef, Thank you for you reply.  module exported was successful . but stop-function and some other functions are missed. ( write-message ..etc..) can you suggest how to import all functions without missing. i can uninstall and install can you please share the stapes. Thank you.

Comment: Check `Get-Module -All -Name Dbatools | ForEach-Object {$_;$_.ExportedCommands | Out-Default}` to ensure that you are importing the desired one.

Answer (score 0):

Some functions are internal to dbatools so will not be visible or available to use independently.

If you look at their GH repository (https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/) you can see a folder called internal that will contain all the internally used functions and scripts that are called/used by the publicly available functions.